# The word *quick* in Latin

Tags: vocabulary, nuance, synonyms, differences

There are many words, which are translated as quick. My initial search showed

- celer: *swift , quick, rapid; in a bad sense, hasty, rash*
- celox: *swift , quick; f. as subst. a swift vessel, yacht*
- citus: *quick, speedy*
- velox: *quick, rapid, swift*

according the the Notre Dame English-Latin dictionary. Did I miss any important word for *quick*?

They all seem pretty the same. Is there any difference between those words? Or can they be used fully interchangeably?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [an entry](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/33197/33197-h/33197-h.htm#word_Citus) (which includes references here omitted) in *Döderlein's Hand-book of Latin Synonymes*:

> Citus; Celer; Velox; Pernix; Properus; Festinus. 1. Citus and celer
>   denote swiftness, merely as quick motion, in opp. to tardus, ... velox
>   and pernix, nimbleness, as bodily strength and activity, in opp. to
>   lentus; properus and festinus, haste, as the will to reach a certain
>   point in the shortest time, in opp. to segnis ... 2. Citus denotes a
>   swift and lively motion, approaching to vegetus; celer, an eager and
>   impetuous motion, approaching to rapidus. 3. Pernicitas is, in
>   general, dexterity and activity in all bodily movements, in hopping,
>   climbing, and vaulting; but velocitas, especially in running, flying,
>   and swimming, and so forth. ... 4. Properus, properare, denote the
>   haste which, from energy, sets out rapidly to reach a certain point,
>   in opp. to cessare; whereas festinus, festinare, denote the haste
>   which springs from impatience, and borders upon precipitation. ...